# How to quickly export multiple files from RStudio

Tags: r, function, file, export

I'd like to know, how can I export subsets of a dataframe in R in an automated way?
I am currently using this manual method, where I retype 'a' and 'file_name' values for every file I want to save:

```
data <- MS[grepl('a', MS$name),] 
write.xlsx(data, 'file_path/file_name')
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A function with 'a' and 'file_name' as input would be ideal.

Comment: Could you clarify - do you have multiple datasets like `MS` and you want to change `MS`, or do you want to find `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. in `MS$name` and export them to different file?

Comment: How does the data look like?

Comment: Didn't make it very clear - yes, I am aiming for the latter - to find a, b, c in MS$name and export them to different files:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
lijst <- c('a','b','c') # list of the values you type for 'a'

for(a in lijst){
   filename <- paste0('file_path/',a,'.xlsx')
   data <- MS[grepl(a, MS$name),] 
   write.xlsx(data, filename)
   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` to define the vector of characters since list is already a function in R, and I dont believe this is what the OP is asking for anyway. I would suggest waiting for clarity from the author before answering.

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem, thanks a lot! liJst works:)